# How to make a correct get queryset with a list in Django to get values

Tags: python, django

I have a list of languages. For example
languages = ['Russian', 'English', 'German', 'Italian', 'French']

And I need to get the id of each language. I'm trying to do it the following way:

```
languages = ['Russian', 'English', 'German', 'Italian', 'French']
languages_to_save = []
for l in languages:
    lang_id = Language.objects.get(lang = l)
    languages_to_save.append(lang_id)
```

But I have an Error:

```
Language matching query does not exist.
```

Though if I change the line to any lanugage in the list, it works correctly. For example:

```
lang_id = Language.objects.get(lang = 'German')
```

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: It means, that one of your langues does not exist in the Language model or is been written with a lower case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of looping through the languages list you can use.

```
languages = ['Russian', 'English', 'German', 'Italian', 'French']
languages_id = Language.objects.filter(lang__in=languages).values_list('id', flat=True)
```

By doing this you will get language id of all the languages which you have specified in the languages list